# Getting parent div to change and activate dropdown when hovered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

Almost there with my menu but the menu I hover over which activates my dropdown will not change colour. Need to match contact-tele to match the dropdown when activated.

Also, is there a way to make the dropdown "sticky", so it will stay open till the dropdown close button is clicked

```
<li class="contact-tele">
  <i class="icon icon-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <span class="contact-text">Call Us</span>
</li>

<div class="dropdown-content">
  <div id="btn-close">
    <img class="popuprd" src="https://s29.postimg.org/627q2j3nr/closewhite.png">
  </div>
  <span style="color:#FBF7E5; padding :1em 0 1em 1em;">London</span>
  <a href="tel:+440200000000">020 000 0000</a>
  <span style="color:#FBF7E5; padding :1em 0 1em 1em;">Manchester</span>
  <a href="tel:+441610000000">0161 000 0000</a>
</div>
```

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24fxcp7y/

Comment: `is there a way to make the dropdown "sticky", so it will stay open till the dropdown close button is clicked` if this is what you required why do you have this code `$('html').click(function() {
   $(".dropdown-content").css('display','none');
});`

Comment: can you check this link [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24fxcp7y/1/)  if I get you right your question

Comment: Thanks Yonus, thats better but the Call Us needs to match colour of dropdown when it is activated

Comment: check this link [demo] (http://jsfiddle.net/24fxcp7y/3/)

Comment: The Call Us has change colour when the dropdown is activated. Exmaple here https://s29.postimg.org/ul8pbr1k7/callus.jpg

Comment: can you check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24fxcp7y/6/) again.

Comment: Almost there, is there a way to make jquery active only if mouse is in the dropdown?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131258/discussion-between-yonas-hailu-and-merch89).